# Case When Condition in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am building one of the reports in SSRS where parameter values can be either NULL or it can contain NON-NULL value.

Now if the value selected by user is NULL (from dropdownlist) then the SQL Query would be

```
field-Name IS NULL
```

If the value selected by user is anything except NULL, the SQL Query would be

```
field-Name IN (@parameter-values)
```

I need to put this condition in WHERE Clause using Case-When so that whatever input is given by user, it is handled by the SQL Query and appropriate result is returned. It could be possible that user selects both NULL and Non-NULL values from dropdownlist.

Please guide as to how to put the "case" condition in where clause OR if any other solutions exists

**Update**:

```
WHERE @IR_Project_Type = 
    (
        CASE WHEN ([IR Project Type] = NULL) THEN ([IR Project Type] IS NULL)
        END 
    )
```

// The 'IS NULL' condition throws an error.

Comment: Show us what you have so far!

Comment: Case in SQL Server is designed to return a single atomic value - not a code block. Not entirely sure what you're trying to do here...

Answer (score 1):

do you admit empty strings as values in field-Name? if not:

```
declare @val varchar(20) = null

select *
from something
where
  ISNULL(@val,'') = ISNULL(fieldName,'');


declare @val varchar(20) = 'aaa'

select *
from something
where
  ISNULL(@val,'') = ISNULL(fieldName,'');
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0b6f/5)

edit:
or just:

```
declare @val varchar(20) = 'aaa'

select * 
from something
where
  (case when @val is null 
     then 
       (case when fieldName is null then 1 else 0 end)
     else
       (case when fieldName = @val then 1 else 0 end) end) = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0b6f/10)

***Please fnd my query.***

```
WHERE (case when @IR_Project_Type is null 
         then 
           (case when [IR Project Type]  is null then 1 else 0 end)
         else
           (case when [IR Project Type]  = @IR_Project_Type then 1 else 0 end) end) = 1
```

Comment: Not sure what your code is trying to do. I added your code into my query and it didn't show desired output when selecting Non-null values. It shows 0 results. It works ok for NULL values.

Comment: are you still using 'IN' ? why are you using it if you are using a variable?

Comment: Nah! I'm not using 'IN', neither I'm using a variable

Comment: "field-Name IN (@parameter-values)" i thought you were using a variable, can you please post your query?

Comment: what type are [IR Project Type] and @IR_Project_Type ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19810/discussion-between-smith-pascal-jr-and-tr3)

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE ((@IR_Project_Type IS NULL AND [IR Project Type] IS NULL) OR [IR Project Type] = @IR_Project_Type)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but this doesn't works for Non-Null values

Comment: When I run the report, the report throws error because the SQL Query is not able to accept multiple values from dropdownlist

Comment: What do you mean, "multiple values"? The user is able to select more than one @IR_Project_Type at a time? If so, exactly **how** are these multiple values passed? Can you give us an example of the query the report is trying to execute when multiple values are selected?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a cheeky OR?

```
WHERE (Field-Name IS NULL OR Field-Name = @parameter)
```

Comment: My first attempt was to use what you suggested. But this doesn't filter out NULL values when selecting ONLY non-null values in the report. Moreover it would be Field-Name IN (@parameter) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE  [IR_Project_Type] = 
    (
        CASE WHEN Isnull(@IR_Project_Type, '') = '' THEN NULL ELSE @IR_Project_Type
        END 
    )
```

Comment: When I run the report, the report throws error because the SQL Query is not able to accept multiple values from dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult (if it's even possible) for an SSRS multi-value parameter to include `null` values.

My usual workaround for this is to use a standard replacement string as a replacement for `NULL`, such as `"<No Value>"`

Then your SQL query can be written with

```
WHERE
  [IR_Project_Type] in ( @IR_Project_Type )
  OR (
     '<No Value>' in ( @IR_Project_Type )
     AND [IR_Project_Type] is NULL
     )
```

This saves a lot of grief in trying to deal with true `NULL`s.